# Code OSS does not execute Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

On my Arch system I have installed jupyter-notebook version 6.4.4 and Code - OSS version 1.61.0. with Python (v2021.9.1246542782) extension and with Jupyter (v2021.9.100) extension.

When I try to open a `.ipynb` file the program returns the following message:

```
Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information.
```

and will not execute the notebook.

If I then toggle the developer tools, what I find is a series of errors of the form:

```
Error: Unable to read file '/usr/lib/code/extensions/markdown-language-features/notebook-out/index.js' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file '/usr/lib/code/extensions/markdown-language-features/notebook-out/index.js')

GET https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-webview.net/usr/lib/code/extensions/markdown-language-features/notebook-out/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-webview.net/usr/lib/code/extensions/markdown-language-features/notebook-out/index.js

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-webview.net/usr/lib/code/extensions/markdown-language-features/notebook-out/index.js
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

having the same issue, the only fix I find was to remove Code - OSS and install Microsoft branded version from AUR (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin/)

Answer (score 3):

you can startup code oss with comand `code --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter` .

it work in oss 1.66

Comment: Worked great for me with vscode-oss 1.67. Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had code 1.61.0 installed from Pacman ==> Did no work.

Version: 1.61.0
Commit: ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea
Date: 2021-10-10T18:20:55.439Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.14.12-arch1-1

Then installed code 1.61.2 from aur ==> works.

Version: 1.61.2
Commit: 6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643
Date: 2021-10-19T14:58:13.605Z
Electron: 13.5.1
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.14.12-arch1-1

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed in Code - OSS version 1.62, which is now available in the official Arch repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed community/code 1.78.1-1, and it's still an issue. Had to run with the command line option `code --enable-proposed-api ms-toolsai.jupyter` to get it to load the jupyter extension.